# Is there a difference between negative mass and negative energy?

Tags: special-relativity, energy, mass-energy, exotic-matter

I was recently reading a bit about negative mass and negative energy. Since mass and energy are linked by the famous equation

$$E=mc^2$$

I would expect that the energy of any mass which is negative also has to be negative - which would mean that they are somewhat the same. Nevertheless, skimming the Wikipedia articles on both [negative mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_mass) and [negative energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_energy), I could find no link between them, implying that they are different phenomena.

So: What is the difference between negative mass and negative energy and how do they curve spacetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me talk about different type of masses and energies by starting with particles with imaginary masses. It comes from the following relation

$$E = \frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$

if one imagine a scenario where the speed of a particle is larger than c, denominator becomes imaginary. In order for energy to be real, mass of tachyons should be imaginary.

In case of virtual particles (check out scattering processes), they don't really have the same mass as their real counterparts but from uncertainty relation as they outlive, their masses asymptotically approach to the real mass values. These particles can have both positive and negative energies.

Negative mass is not something we can find in nature and experiment but theoretically speaking if you push a particle with negative mass, it will come towards you and vice versa. Also they won't be thrown away by the gravitational force exerted by earth, on the contrary they will fall like positive-mass particles since the gravitational force will be pushing these negative masses (not pulling like in ordinary matter), they will move opposite to the direction of applied force.

Since energy and mass are related, if mass is negative

$$E = mc^2 < 0$$

From the above "free fall" example, you see there won't be any orbits so the curvature of spacetime will be in such a way that all the stars and matter will be pushed away from the sources (negative mass stars and etc).

When people don't want to deal with negative energies, they pick up the negative solution $E = -mc^2 $ from energy-momentum relation

$$E^2 = (m_0 c^2)^2 + (pc)^2$$

if the momentum term is $0$. This makes the energy positive when the mass is negative.